# Finding cross-over point for Merge and Select sort in Python

Tags: python, arrays, sorting, mergesort, insertion-sort

For an assignment I have to implement merge and insertion sort into Python *(this code was given to us)*.

However, I then have to "run experiments" with the `timeit` function to test the runtimes of both algorithms and then make a graph to determine their cross point, or when the input crosses the threshold where merge becomes better than insertion (something stated in the prompt of the problem).

Here is my code:

```
import random
import timeit
import array

# Insertion sort routine
def insertion_sort(A):
    for k in range (1, len(A)): #from 1 to n-1
        curr = A[k] #currently inserting element
        j = k #find correct index j for current
        while j > 0 and A[j - 1] > curr:
            A[j] = A[j - 1]
            j -= 1
            A[j] = curr


# Merge sort routines
def merge(S1, S2, S):
    i = j = 0

    while i + j < len(S):
        if j == len(S2) or (i < len(S1) and S1[i] < S2[j]):
            S[i + j] = S1[i]
            i += 1
        else:
            S[i + j] = S2[j]
            j += 1

def merge_sort(S):
    n = len(S)
    if n < 2:
        return

    mid = n // 2

    S1 = S[0:mid]
    S2 = S[mid:n]

    merge_sort(S1)
    merge_sort(S2)
    merge(S1, S2, S)

# Benchmark code
S = array.array('B',(0,)*300)
A = array.array('b', (0,)*300)
print(timeit.timeit("merge_sort(S)", setup = "from __main__ import merge_sort, S", number = 1))
print(timeit.timeit("insertion_sort(A)", setup = "from __main__ import insertion_sort, A", number = 1))
```

For an array with length 300. No matter what size I change my array to, merge is always better than insertion.

**What am I missing here? How can I fix this?**

Comment: Python code depends on indentation, so make sure that the your code is properly formatted (for example, in your `insertion_sort` function, the while-loop is now executed after the for-loop). Also, it seems you're just sorting zeroes.

Comment: I do think part of it is how I'm initializing my array occupied with zeroes. Also i think the indent problems are just with my formatting in SO, in my program everything is indented correctlyl

Comment: I suggested some edits for the code indentation - please check that it agrees with what you had in mind.